Even fluid distribution in horizontal irrigation for vertical gardening
I would like to place several vertical planters in several rows to create a closed hydroponic system. If I just make equal holes in a pipe and then pump my solution from the container to the pipe - the solution drops from the first 2-3 holes and doesn't reach the rest (while the first hole gets the most fluid, the second - less, etc.). What is the easiest practical way to distribute the fluid evenly between all the holes in one pipe and between several such pipes placed in parallel? If there are pictures/videos (or links) on how to do it - it would be great!

Your holes are too large for the rate you are pumping.


easiest practical way

Pressure-compensating drip emitters, fed solution at pressures within their operating range.
Since you mention "vertical planters" one of your issues is that the pressure at the highest planter/pipe will be less than at the lowest planter/pipe.
Make sure that the highest pressure does not exceed the highest operating pressure of the emitters, and the lowest pressure is not less than the minimum operating pressure, or flow will not be even between the emitters.
